# Knockout JS - observable array needs to be populated from the detail object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasanvee/yYEwJ/2/

I have a list which has category, product, quantity as columns, 
I have the option to add new category from the dropdown itself (select --Add new-- option),
wanted to populate the categoryList observableArray from the category subscribe method (since the newly added value has to be applied to all the rows of the grid),
Not sure how to do that, tried with $root.categoryList.push(name), but no luck

Or do we have even better way of handling this scenario?
help on this really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables like `$root` are only available within the bindings.

One way to make this work is to pass a reference to your root view model to your cartLine constructor.

Your cartLine would end up looking like:

```
var cartLine = function(data1, root) {
    this.category = ko.observable(data1.category);
    this.product = ko.observable(data1.product);
    this.quantity = ko.observable(data1.quantity);

    this.category.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (newValue == "--Add New--") {
            var name = prompt("Enter Table Name");
            if (name == null) {  
                return false;
            }
            else {
                root.categoryList.push(name);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Then, you just need to pass `this` in as the second argument from your view model when creating a new cartLine.  Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kzZSH/

Otherwise, you could create your cartLine as you were and subscribe from your viewModel after getting a reference to the new line back.